# Haskell. Tangled with String, typeclasses and TagSoup library

Tags: haskell

Good day, i trying to use TagSoup library in my project and stuck at begining.

Tagsoup has StringLike class for some i guess honored purpose and i cant understand how to cope with it propertly. I wrote function:

```
parseFile :: (StringLike str) => String -> IO [Tag str]
parseFile f = do
  html <- readFile f
  return $ parseTags html
```

which gives me:

> Couldn't match expected type `str' against inferred type`[Char]'
>   `str' is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for`parseFile'   Expected type: IO [Tag
>   str]   Inferred type: IO [Tag String]

but TagSoup's 'parseTags' function has such signature and works well:

```
parseTags :: StringLike str => str -> [Tag str]
```

Mine works ok if i change its signature to:

```
parseFile :: String -> IO [Tag String]
```

But i like my functions also reatin this typeclassed signature, not strictly String, how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the type of `parseTags`:

```
parseTags :: StringLike str => str -> [Tag str]
```

The type variable `str` has to be *the same* in the input and the output. Since the input comes from `readFile :: FilePath -> IO String`, the input will be a `String`, so the output will have to be `[Tag String]`.

However, the `StringLike` class contains the function [`fromString :: StringLike str => String -> str`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tagsoup/latest/doc/html/Text-StringLike.html#t%3aStringLike), so you can use this function to convert the type.

```
parseFile :: (StringLike str) => String -> IO [Tag str]
parseFile f = do
  html <- readFile f
  return $ parseTags (fromString html)
```

I haven't tested it, but this should hopefully do the job.

Comment: Cool, it works with fromString, but is there another way ? using function to convert from string to actually same string seems like little overhead for me.

Comment: There is no overhead, the compiler will remove that.

Comment: @Dfr: Well, in the `StringLike` instance for `String`, `fromString = id`, so there is hardly any overhead. You could of course try to load it straight into the correct type from the file, but then you would have to create another typeclass for that, as `StringLike` does not have any `readFile`-like operation.

Comment: You aren't converting from String to String; you're converting from String to whatever StringLike type the function's caller expects, which will in some but not all cases be String.

Comment: By overhead i meant amount of source code, so when you start using Tagsoup matching functions, there same problem will arise, so your parser code (yet not very terse) additionally will be bloated with numerous fromString calls.

Comment: @Dfr: This source code overhead is one of the tradeoffs of a language with no implicit casting of types. One of the rewards is that parseTags can be very general, not caring about whether the actual type you give it is really a string or a bytestring, or any other datatype you could define, which behaves like a string.